# scrollbarRef is undefined inside NGX Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I am showing a list of user's inside NGX Bootstrap modal, using `BsModalService`. I am also using a [custom scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scrollbar) inside modal. I have found an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scrollbar-1d2u1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts) to detect when scrollbar reaches end.

On modal shown I tried to get the `this.scrollbarRef.scrollable` instance but angular showing an error **scrollable of undefined**. On Reached end of the scroll container I am trying to load more user's(Scroll Pagination).

**Component HTML -**

```
<ng-template #userModal>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="user-list">
            <ng-scrollbar
               #scrollable
               [compact]="true"
               [shown]="'hover'"
               class="search-custom-scroll"
               barClass="search-custom-scroll-bar"
               thumbClass="search-custom-scroll-thumb"
            >
              .....
            </ng-scrollbar>
         </div>
      </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Component TS -**

```
openModal(modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>){
      this._modalService.onShown.subscribe(() => {
          console.log(this.scrollbarRef.scrollable)
      })
      this.modalRef = this._modalService.show(modalTemplate, this.modalConfig);
    }
```

Comment: can you show the rest of the component on how the _scrollbarRef_ looks like? Can you see it being populated in the modal though?

Comment: yes, the scrollbar is getting populated in the modal